# Question about the proof of Rouche's theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

This is the proof given in Stein, Shakarchi's complex analysis text:[image]

So every is fine except for the final paragraph? So I understand that the integrand is continuous, but I am not sure why $n_t$ which is also the integral of the integrand just as a function of $t$ would also be continuous. Why is that the case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$n_t$ is realised as a function $n:[0,1]\to\Bbb C,\,t\mapsto n_t$.

Let $H:C\times[0,1]\to\Bbb C$ the homotopy $(z,t)\mapsto f(z)+t\cdot g(z)$. We are given that $H$ has no zeroes in its image. $H$ is obviously continuous, and $C\times[0,1]$ is compact, so $H(C\times[0,1])$ must be bounded away from zero in modulus. There is some $\delta>0$ that $|H(z,t)|>\delta$ for all $(z,t)\in C\times[0,1]$. It follows that $f'_t(z)/f_t(z)$ is jointly continuous in $t,z$.

Why is the integral of a jointly continuous quantity $g(z,t)$ jointly continuous? Well, the differences will be: $$\oint_C[g(z,t+h)-g(z,h)]$$And again because $C\times[0,1]$ is compact, $g$ will be uniformly continuous. That implies that $|g(z,t+h)-g(z,h)|$ can be made *uniformly* small if $h$ is sufficiently small, to an arbitrary degree of smallness. If you take the finite integral of a small quantity, you get again a small quantity.

More precisely, if $\epsilon>0$ is taken, and $M$ is the perimeter length of the circle, there is a $\delta>0$ such that $|g(z,t+h)-g(z,h)|<\epsilon/M$ for all $|h|<\delta$ and all suitable $z,t$. So: $$\left|\oint_C[g(z,t+h)-g(z,t)]\right|\le\oint_C|[g(z,t+h)-g(z,t)]|\le\oint_C\epsilon/M=\epsilon$$Whenever $|h|<\delta$. It follows that $t\mapsto\oint_Cg(z,t)$ is continuous.

Comment: thank you for the explanation. I just want to clarify , since we are given |f|>|g| on the circle only, but not necessarily on the interior, did you mean to say that H on C x [0,1] have no zeros? If you mean the whole disk, D, then the image by H may have zeroes  right?

Comment: @davidh Sorry, you’re right, it was a silly mistake to use $D$ over $C$. But $C$ is still compact